# Add class dynamically to td on click and toggle and remove when other td is clicked in angular/typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, reactjs, typescript

I am working in angular app where I am working on COVID 19 app.I have table with 5 columns

- 1. STATE
- 2. CONFIRMED
- 3. ACTIVE
- 4. RECOVERED
- 5. DECEASED

Here is my stack blitz link[stack blitz link](https://stackblitz.com/github/mehulk05/COVOID-19).

Also here is the reference of my expectation [Expectation](https://www.covid19india.org/).

On clicking any column I am sorting my whole table data in ascending or descending order and displaying an up arrow for ascending and down arrow for descending.

**My problem** is when I click on any column all the arrows on all columns get changed where as I only want to change arrow for the column I have clicked  and hide arrows for other columns. Also initially when page loads my arrow should not get visible ,instead they should be only visible when i click on any column.

Here is my code

**component.html**

```
               <tr>
                    <th (click)="sortAscending(sortedDataBasedOnDate)" class="sticky state-heading">
                        <div class="heading-content"><abbr title="State">State/UT</abbr>
                            <div [ngClass]="showarrow  ? 'down-arrow' : 'up-arrow'"></div>
                        </div>
                    </th>

                    <th (click)="sortByMaxCases(sortedDataBasedOnDate)" class="sticky">
                        <div class="heading-content"><abbr class="" title="Confirmed">Confirmed</abbr>
                            <div [ngClass]="showarrow  ? 'down-arrow' : 'up-arrow'"></div>
                        </div>
                    </th>

                    <th (click)="sortByMaxActive(sortedDataBasedOnDate)" class="sticky">
                        <div class="heading-content"><abbr class="" title="Active">Active</abbr>
                            <div [ngClass]="showarrow  ? 'down-arrow' : 'up-arrow'"></div>
                        </div>
                    </th>

                    <th (click)="sortByMaxRecovered(sortedDataBasedOnDate)" class="sticky">
                        <div class="heading-content"><abbr class="" title="Recovered">Recovered</abbr>
                            <div></div>
                            <div [ngClass]="showarrow  ? 'down-arrow' : 'up-arrow'"></div>
                        </div>
                    </th>

                    <th (click)="sortByMaxDeath(sortedDataBasedOnDate)" class="sticky">
                        <div class="heading-content"><abbr class="" title="Deaths">Deceased</abbr>
                            <div [ngClass]="showarrow  ? 'down-arrow' : 'up-arrow'"></div>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
```

**Component.ts**

```
 showarrow=false


 sortAscending(data) {
    this.isAscendingSort = !this.isAscendingSort;
    this.showarrow=true                                 // setting here
    data.forEach(item => item.statewise.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (b.state < a.state) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (b.state > a.state) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }))
    this.calculateDiff(this.sortedDataBasedOnDate)

    if (!this.isAscendingSort) {
    this.showarrow=!this.showarrow           // for descending toggling class here
      let a = data.forEach(item => item.statewise.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.state < b.state) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.state > b.state) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      }))
      this.calculateDiff(this.sortedDataBasedOnDate)
    }
  }
```

Also I have tried this approach for initially hide arrows on page load but it have same problem that if I click on any column arrow will appear on all column.

**Component.html**

```
   <div class="heading-content"><abbr title="State">State/UT</abbr>
        <div [ngClass]="{'down-arrow':showarrowdesc , 'up-arrow' : 
         showarrowasc,'hide':hide}"></div>

    </div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
 showarrowasc=false
 showarrowdesc=false
 hide=true

 sortAscending(data) {
    this.isAscendingSort = !this.isAscendingSort;
    this.showarrowasc=!this.showarrowasc
    this.showarrowdesc=false
    
    data.forEach(item => item.statewise.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (b.state < a.state) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (b.state > a.state) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }))
    this.calculateDiff(this.sortedDataBasedOnDate)

    if (!this.isAscendingSort) {
    
    this.showarrowdesc=!this.showarrowdesc;
    this.showarrowasc=false
      let a = data.forEach(item => item.statewise.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.state < b.state) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.state > b.state) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      }))
      this.calculateDiff(this.sortedDataBasedOnDate)
    }
  }
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: The way you are doing things here will have to wrote some unnecessary codes to achieve that. I would prefer create a json object with field, sorting etc and create a table using loop, In that case you need only sorting function and one function to get the correct icons to update the table

Comment: Can you please give me a little demo on any test data I am a beigner in angular

Comment: You can go through this link to get an idea about it. https://medium.com/@mjthakur413/how-to-create-table-in-angular-7-using-ngfor-3c2c0875b955.

Comment: Seriously that was your answer I am not learning how to make table .What i want is toggle arrows onClick of particular  coloumns

Comment: yes, the way you are creating a table is full with unnecessary codes. Create a dynamic table , use power of angular framework or use some built in data-tables packages.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are cutting your provided code as I cannot see sortByMaxCases() (and the others except for sortAscending()) which you are calling from your template.

Then, from what I can see here it seems that you are toggling all columns with the same boolean: showarrow.

To overcome this you could for example create an object that holds multiple properties, one for each column, like so:

```js
const showArrows = {
    confirmed: false,
    active: false
}
```

Add all the other columns that you have as well and define one as true as an initial sorting.

Then in your template reference that object as follows:

```html
<th (click)="sortAscending(sortedDataBasedOnDate)" class="sticky state-heading">
    <div class="heading-content"><abbr title="State">Confirmed</abbr>
        <div [ngClass]="showArray.confirmed ? 'down-arrow' : 'up-arrow'"></div>
    </div>
</th>
```

As an example for the confirmed column.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So should I add show array for my 5 coloumns with 10 properties show hide for eavh coloumn??  @gerstams

Comment: I don't quite understand your question here. I suggest to create an object (not an array) with n properties (n being the number of columns you have). And then use those properties in your template.

Comment: Also this wont be efficient way because I have so many tables and for all those I cant do same!!!  @gerstams

Comment: If it is too much work and you don't want to do that yourself, maybe check Angular materials sort header: https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview. This abstracts most of the code away and you basically only need to provide your columns, column headers and data once

Comment: OKay that is something interestng